# ArrayList in HashMap kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, hashmap

How to add some value in ArrayList which is inside of HashMap? My bellow code showing 0 sizes of the hash

```
val hash= HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> >()
    hash["bro"]?.add("Ali Umar")
    hash["sis"]?.add("Tamanna")
    hash["bro"]?.add("Faruk")
    hash["sis"]?.add("Aklima")
    hash["bro"]?.add("Ab Siddik")
    Log.d("Hash", hash.size.toString())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize a `List` and put the key and that initialized `List` into the `HashMap` before you can add any more items to the value of a key. In your example code nothing is put into the `HashMap` and nothing can be added.

Try it like this (or similar)

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // initialize the hashmap
    val hash = hashMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
    // put the keys with empty lists into the hashmap
    hash.put("bro", mutableListOf())
    hash.put("sis", mutableListOf())
    // add items to the value (the list) of existing keys
    hash.get("bro")?.add("Ali Umar")
    hash.get("sis")?.add("Tamanna")
    hash.get("bro")?.add("Faruk")
    hash.get("sis")?.add("Aklima")
    hash.get("bro")?.add("Ab Siddik")
    // print size and content
    println("Hash size is ${hash.size.toString()}")
    println(hash)
}
```

In the Kotlin Playground this outputs

```
Hash size is 2
{sis=[Tamanna, Aklima], bro=[Ali Umar, Faruk, Ab Siddik]}
```

Comment: Many many thanks, bro!. I have also a problem. I want a map like a c++ (stl library's map) in kotlin. But in kotlin hashmap work just as a reference. for example, if I set a value to Hashmap from a variable and then change the value of that variable, the Hashmap value also changed . But I don't want it. I want just like as c++ stl map. How to I dot it? Also advance thanks bro.

Comment: Thanks bro, I got the solution of above problem by using `.toMutableList()`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the following instructions are just reading from the hashmap but not inserting anything

```
hash["bro"]
hash["sis"]
```

so when you create your hashmap with  `val hash= HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> >()` it is empty and "bro" and "sis" do not exist. so it is null and the add function will not be called because of `?.` skips execution if the value is null.

so to add something to bro and sis you first have to put values to your hashmap.

```
hash.put("bro",ArrayList<String>())
hash.put("sis",ArrayList<String>())
```

this would change your example as follows

```
val hash= HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> >()
    hash.put("bro",ArrayList<String>())
    hash.put("sis",ArrayList<String>())
    hash["bro"]?.add("Ali Umar")
    hash["sis"]?.add("Tamanna")
    hash["bro"]?.add("Faruk")
    hash["sis"]?.add("Aklima")
    hash["bro"]?.add("Ab Siddik")
    Log.d("Hash", hash.size.toString())
```